# How to save multiple items when user selects from a uitableview to nsuserdefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save any of the items as user selects from a uitableview to nsuserdefaults. At that moment only the most recent selection is saved. I would like to have the user to be able to select any of the rows they want and then saved to nsuserdefaults and then use that info anywhere in the app.

thanks for any help

here's my code:

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // categories array
    listOfCategories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [listOfCategories addObject:@"Food & Drinks"];
    [listOfCategories addObject:@"Beauty & Wellness"];
    [listOfCategories addObject:@"Sports & Fun Activities"];
    [listOfCategories addObject:@"Labor & Services"];
    [listOfCategories addObject:@"Clothes & Accessories"];
    [listOfCategories addObject:@"Education & Training"];
    [listOfCategories addObject:@"Products"];

    // add label
    UIView *viewForHeader = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,40)];
    UILabel *categoryLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,80,30)];
    categoryLabel.text = @"Select all:";

    [categoryLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Bold" size: 14.0f]];
    categoryLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    // add switch
    onoff = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(100.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f)];
    [onoff addTarget: self action: @selector(flipSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [viewForHeader addSubview:onoff];

    [viewForHeader addSubview:categoryLabel];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = viewForHeader;

}

// uiswitch button
- (IBAction) flipSwitch: (id) sender {
    onoff = (UISwitch *) sender;
    NSLog(@"%@", onoff.on ? @"On" : @"Off");

    if (onoff.on) {
        for (NSInteger s = 0; s < self.tableView.numberOfSections; s++) {
            for (NSInteger r = 0; r < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:s]; r++) {
                [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:r inSection:s]
                                            animated:NO
                                      scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [listOfCategories count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }        // Configure the cell...

    NSString *cellValue = [listOfCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Bold" size: 14.0f]];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    int index = indexPath.row; id obj = [listOfCategories objectAtIndex:index];


    //This toggles the checkmark
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-tick.png"];

        UIButton *downloadButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        [downloadButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [downloadButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 19, 19)];
        [downloadButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = downloadButton;

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        //This sets the array

    } else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        UIButton *downloadButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [downloadButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [downloadButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = downloadButton;


    }

    // Save text of the selected cell:
    UITableViewCell *cellSelected = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([cellSelected.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Food & Drinks"]) {
        NSString *valueToSave = cellSelected.textLabel.text;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
         setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"preferenceName"];

    }

    NSString *valueToSave = cellSelected.textLabel.text;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
     setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"preferenceName"];


    NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];

    NSLog(@"savedValue %@", savedValue);

    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    // Customize archiver here
    [archiver encodeObject:obj forKey:@"keyForYourArrayOfNSIndexPathObjects"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"keyForYourArrayOfNSIndexPathObjects"];


    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver;
    unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:
                  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"keyForYourArrayOfNSIndexPathObjects"]];
    // Customize unarchiver here
    categoryItemSelected = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"keyForYourArrayOfNSIndexPathObjects"];
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];

    NSLog(@"list of categories selected %@", categoryItemSelected);


}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you overridden the previously saved data.
So first of all you need to load saved data:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver;
unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:
              [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"keyForYourArrayOfNSIndexPathObjects"]];
// Customize unarchiver here
categoryItemSelected = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"keyForYourArrayOfNSIndexPathObjects"];
[unarchiver finishDecoding];
if (categoryItemSelected == nil) {
    //If it isn't been created - then create new array
}
```

Then add new object:

```
[categoryItemSelected addObject: obj];
```

And then save it back to UserDefautls

Comment: thanks :) at the moment though it does save the title of a selected cell to nsuserdefaults. I just need it to add a second and third selection to the array if a user selects them